# Insert array data to each table column

Tags: php, mysql

Here is an array from the `print_r($_POST)`

```
Array
(
    [january] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 5
        )

    [february] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 10
        )

    [march] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

)
```

Loop for `$_POST`.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $data[] = $value;
}
```

Statement

```
INSERT INTO table (january,february,march) VALUES (".implode(", ", $data).")
```

With this current array how do I make a correct statement? I want to store the data something like this

```
id january february march
--------------------------
1  10      9        2
2  20      8        5
3  5       10       6
```

Comment: Try to write a query manually at first. So a complete query that inserts 3 rows with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$month = array("january" => array(10, 20, 5), "february" => array(1,2,3), "march" => array(3,4,5));

$datasets = array();

foreach ($month as $monthname => $monthdata)
{
    foreach ($monthdata as $i => $data)
    {
        $datasets[$i][] = intval($data);
    }
}

$values = array();

foreach ($datasets as $dataset)
{
    $values[] = "(" . implode(", ", $dataset) . ")";
}


echo "INSERT INTO table (january,february,march) VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);
```

I have put an `intval` in the code to apply some "basic security" because you should never insert users data unfiltered in your database. Inform yourself about prepared statements and mysql escaping, please ;).

Comment: `intval` is not a proper substitute for escaping. This would be a billion times safer with placeholders instead of actual data.

Comment: What security vulnerability could you possibly have after intval'ing the input?

Comment: `intval` creates a false sense of security. It's not a general purpose solution to a serious problem. Basically it's a red flag for bad escaping practices.

Comment: I still don't get it. It fixes all sql injection vulnerabilities and if you want an int anyway, what's the big deal? I mean yeah, you could use filter_var which is able to do some range checking whatsoever, but as a basic approach, I don't see the problem.

Comment: What do you do about string data, then? `intval` isn't going to help you there. It also mangles decimal values and can't handle booleans or dates. It's so narrow a solution as to be useless in general practice.

Comment: I have never claimed that `intval` is a sophisticated general purpose approach or that it makes prepared statements / escaping obsolete in any way. In my post, it was targeted at the concrete problem of the op who has to deal with normal ints.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do:

```
$rows=sizeof($_POST['january']);#find how many rows we want to add
for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
  $columns=array();
  $values=array();
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $columns[]=$key;
    $values[]=$value;
  }
  $sql="INSERT INTO table (".implode(",",$columns).") VALUES (".implode(",",$values).")"
  mysql_query($sql)
}
```

Comment: If that's your idea of how to do it, you **really** need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because this is absolutely terrifying. Do not do this. Ever. Stop using `mysql_query` for the sake of humanity.

Comment: I was just using the same format that the OP was using.  The question was more about the php side of things than mysql.  You shouldn't downvote for that.

Comment: If someone puts this into production, it would create a gaping security hole. Since this promotes recklessly bad practices, it's not a good answer. Adding escaping might be annoying, but it makes the answer *correct* and *safe*.